# jQuery doesn't animate my background colo

Tags: jquery, background, jquery-animate, background-color

I have been trying to animate the background color of my web site. I have try many way but it does not work at all.

I want to use this in other part of the code but just this doesn't work :

```
jQuery('div#Wrapper').animate({backgroundColor:'rgb(7,100,172)'),8500);
```

Comment: Is your syntax error (missing closing `}` in animate options) also present in your actual code, or just a typo here?

Comment: Did you include jQuery ui? Just jQuery can't animate colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your syntax error (use closing bracket in place of parenthesis), and include jQuery first, then jQuery UI.

```
jQuery('div#Wrapper').animate({backgroundColor:'rgb(7,100,172)'},8500);
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JhcVd/)

Comment: i have insert this :  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script> but Include jQuery UI doesn't solve my probleme or may be i miss something

Comment: @user2722671 You need to include jQuery before including jQuery UI. Always check your console when having jQuery/javascript problems.

Answer (score 1):

If your div has an id of Wrapper then your syntax should be

```
$('#Wrapper').animate({backgroundColor:'rgb(7,100,172)'},8500);
```

you are also missing your closing `}` for your `animate` funciton

Comment: this is a great comment.

Comment: i said this because at the time you didnt actually solve his problem, u just told him to remove the `div` qualifier in the selector. its a valid point, but not worthy of answer. even now, though, your answer is incorrect because it closes the parenthesis before the timing value.

Comment: i try your solution, unfortunatly, this doesn't seems to work.
like i say, i try many solutions:

I see that jQuery does try something.
My div look like this:
<div id="Wrapper">
before the code begin and look like this after:
<div id="Wrapper" style="">

the probleme is on my website i try to animate the background to be more cool.
This is the adress: www.godartmartin.com

And thank you for your quick reply

Comment: @user2722671 have you included jQuery UI? Is there an error in the console?